# Why create own request object?

Tags: php, post, get, request

Im building an own php framework. I saw in other frameworks there are even object for doing this, but I cant see the reason why not just use POST and GET arrays directly. Moreover, how to decide when POST or GET? What if there are variables in both area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement your own request/response objects to:

1. Have better control over what and where to get/put and over the application flow in common
2. Abstract from a request type HTTP/CLI/...

Comment: Additionally, you may want to sanitize the input from _POST and _GET (or _REQUEST) so the user doesn't have to (or can't forget to) sanitize it himself and can use it directly.

Comment: @SJFrK: this is a bad advice, because until you know what you need the data to sanitize for - you cannot do so. And NO, there is no any universal sanitization algorithm

Comment: That might be true, but if you're posting around \0 or pure javascript code and stuff, you really should rethink your programming logic.

Comment: @SJFrK: once again: **absolutely any input** can be valid for some particular case. Even null-byte and pure javascript. So **it is** true